# Spark Structured Streaming Kafka Microbatch count

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am using Spark structured streaming to read records from a Kafka topic; I intend to count the number of records received in each 'Micro batch' in Spark `readstream`

This is a snippet:

```scala
val kafka_df = sparkSession
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:port")
  .option("subscribe", "test-count")
  .load()
```

I understand from the docs that kafka_df will be lazily evaluated when a `streamingQuery` is started (to come next), and as it is evaluated, it holds a micro-batch. So, I figured doing a `groupBy` on *topic* followed by a `count` should work.

Like this:

```scala
val counter = kafka_df
             .groupBy("topic")
             .count()
```

Now to evaluate all of this, we need a streaminQuery, lets say, a console sink query to print it on the console. And this is where i see the problem. A streamingQuery on `aggregate` DataFrames, such as `kafka_df` works only with `outputMode` ***complete/update*** and not on ***append***.

This effectively means that, the count reported by the streamingQuery is cumulative.

Like this:

```scala
 val counter_json = counter.toJSON   //to jsonify 
 val count_query = counter_json
                   .writeStream.outputMode("update")
                   .format("console")
                   .start()          // kicks of lazy evaluation
                   .awaitTermination()
```

In a controlled set up, where:
 actual Published records: 1500
 actual Received micro-batches : 3
aActual Received records: 1500

The count of each microbatch is supposed to be **500**, so I hoped (wished) that the query prints to console:

> topic: test-count
>      count: 500
>   topic: test-count
>   count: 500
>   topic: test-count
>   count: 500

But it doesn't. It actually prints:

> topic: test-count
>      count: 500
>   topic: test-count
>   count:1000
>   topic: test-count
>   count: 1500

This I understand is because of 'outputMode' *complete/update* (cumulative)

My question: Is it possible to accurately get the count of each micro-batch is Spark-Kafka structured streaming?

From the docs, I found out about the watermark approach (to support append):

```scala
val windowedCounts = kafka_df
                    .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 seconds")
                    .groupBy(window($"timestamp", "10 seconds", "10       seconds"), $"topic")
                    .count()

 val console_query = windowedCounts
                    .writeStream
                    .outputMode("append")
                    .format("console")
                    .start()
                    .awaitTermination()
```

But the results of this `console_query` are inaccurate and appears is way off mark.

TL;DR - Any thoughts on accurately counting the records in Spark-Kafka micro-batch would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to only process a specific number of records with every trigger within a Structured Streaming application using Kafka, use the option `maxOffsetsPerTrigger`

```scala
val kafka_df = sparkSession
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host:port")
  .option("subscribe", "test-count")
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 500)
  .load()
```

Comment: I intend to count the number of records per batch and not limit it. This could also be extended to aggregating some numeric data (sourced from kafka) per batch. The problem for me here is in achieving 'append' mode, where 'aggregation' for each batch is sent to another Kafka Sink. 
Whereas, currently I observe that this aggregation is cumulative.

Answer (score 2):

> "TL;DR - Any thoughts on accurately counting the records in Spark-Kafka micro-batch would be appreciated."

You can count the records fetched from Kafka by using a `StreamingQueryListener` ([ScalaDocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQueryListener.html)).

This allows you to print out the exact number of rows that were received from the subscribed Kafka topic. The `onQueryProgress` API gets called during every micro-batch and contains *lots of* useful meta information on your query. If no data is flowing into the query the onQueryProgress is called every 10 seconds. Below is a simple example that prints out the number of input messages.

```
spark.streams.addListener(new StreamingQueryListener() {
    override def onQueryStarted(queryStarted: QueryStartedEvent): Unit = {}

    override def onQueryTerminated(queryTerminated: QueryTerminatedEvent): Unit = {}

    override def onQueryProgress(queryProgress: QueryProgressEvent): Unit = {
      println("NumInputRows: " + queryProgress.progress.numInputRows)
    }
  })
```

In case you are validating the performance of your Structured Streaming query, it is usually best to keep an eye on the following two metrics:

- `queryProgress.progress.inputRowsPerSecond`
- `queryProgress.progress.processedRowsPerSecond`

In case *input* is higher than *processed* you might increase resources for your job or reduce the maximum limit (by reducing the readStream option maxOffsetsPerTrigger). If processed is higher, you may want to increase this limit.

Comment: queryProgress.progress.numInputRows is number of rows written to target sink. so be remember if you are writing it into multiple sinks or doing any operation like df.count in the foreachbtach, it is not going to be exact number of message received originally.  for example. you receive 10 events and you fork it and write it to 2 sinks. it is going to be 20, not 10. also if a batch has multiple topics subscribed, it is the sum of messages received for all topics. i was figuring out how to get the message count per topic. no hope. appreciate if someone has any idea