# Spark Structured Streaming - Streaming data joined with static data which will be refreshed every 5 mins

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

For spark structured streaming job one input is coming from a kafka topic while second input is a file (which will be refreshed every 5 mins by a python API). I need to join these 2 inputs and write to a kafka topic.

The issue I am facing is when second input file is being refreshed and spark streaming job is reading the file at the same time I get the error below:

> File file:/home/hduser/code/new/collect_ip1/part-00163-55e17a3c-f524-4dac-89a4-b9e12f1a79df-c000.csv does not exist
>   It is possible the underlying files have been updated. You can explicitly invalidate the cache in Spark by recreating the Dataset/DataFrame involved.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How is that python API working?

Comment: Python API gets the data from remote server in the form of files.

Comment: So just adding files to a directory. But at rest? What do you mean bu updating?

Comment: Files are categorized into Major files and Minor Files.When only minor files comes we need to append the data to the existing directory,if a Major files comes need to delete the data in the directory and add new data.The Spark streaming job reads this directory as second input .When ever this refresh is happening i am facing the issue mentioned.

Comment: It's the delete. That simple.

Comment: Add the data and do a distinct, but how big is the data for 2nd source?

Comment: Currently size of the major file  varies from 300 MB to 400 MB.

Comment: Not a good approach.

Comment: Could you tell me the the best possible approach

Comment: how much data on input per microbatch? can u check broadcast has join takes place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HBase as your store for static. It is more work for sure but allows for concurrent updating.

Where I work, all Spark Streaming uses HBase for lookup of data. Far faster. What if you have a 100M customers for a microbatch of 10k records? I know it was a lot of work initially.

See https://medium.com/@anchitsharma1994/hbase-lookup-in-spark-streaming-acafe28cb0dc

If you have a small static ref table, then static join is fine, but you also have updating, causing issues.

Comment: Thanks for the info.Appreciate your help.Could you let me know how find  the size of a micro batch in spark streaming

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731800/spark-structured-streaming-kafka-microbatch-count